# Extract Address from String - Equivalent to NSDataDetector in iOS

Tags: java, android, google-geocoder, street-address, nsdatadetector

In iOS there's a class named `NSDataDetector` that, for example, let's you pass a text and it will detect if that text contains things like postal addresses, dates, links...

In my case, I'm interested in finding a similar tool for Android that let will detect an address inside a text. I've playing around with the `Geocoder`, but it only works if you already know the address; otherwise, it won't serve the purpose.

An example of what I'm looking for might be:

Given:

`This is just a sample text that contains a nice address: 123 W Main St, Imaginary City, IC, 12345`

The tool would return just `123 W Main St, Imaginary City, IC, 12345`

Keep in mind that the address might have different formats.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SmartyStreets (Disclaimer: I work for them) has an address [Extract API](https://smartystreets.com/docs/us-extract-api) (demo [here](https://smartystreets.com/api-demo#extract)). It's built specifically for this purpose. Not only will it extract your address from a string, but it will also validate your address. You can either call the API directly, or use the [built in tool on the account page](https://smartystreets.com/account#extract).

There are probably other companies that offer this same service, I just can't think of any.

Comment: Is this tool only valid for US addresses, or is it able to work with different formats too?

Comment: @Jorge currently it only works for US addresses. Addresses in other countries have more variants in how they are constructed and are more difficult to parse.